# How to normalize image to interval 0 to 1

Tags: java, image-processing, jai

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I normalize an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695084/how-do-i-normalize-an-image)

I am working on the implementation of active contours with gradient vector flow. I need to normalize the input image in the interval from 0 to 1 Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this in JAVA or JAI. If you can help me with some of your code or some link which can me help, many thanks.

Comment: What have you read or tried already?

Comment: **[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695084/how-do-i-normalize-an-image)** post may be of help.

Comment: thanks for the link, helped me. And sorry for duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an already existing library, I can recommend [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/), which has a good set of image processing algorithms. You can find more in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3501811/1137043).

If you want to implement it yourself, that's quiet easy. Find maximum and minimum of your image in a run, then run over it again, rescaling every point.